# Retaining HTML table row order with the MySQL insert function

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm using a simple to PHP and jQuery script to send data from an HTML table into my datatabse. It collects the values from every `td` in each row and inserts it into the database. This is quite a general question, but how would I ensure the row order of the table is retained when adding the values into the database?

I realise that `ORDER BY` can't be used on insertion, and I will be regularly inserting the same table with different data in it each time so I can't use a row ID field to return the order accurately as duplicates will occur. Each `tr` does have an ID though (a function I'm not currently utilising in the script below), so is there anything we can do to on the jQuery end to ensure records are inserted in some kind of order?

**jQuery script:**

```
 $('#myModal').on('click', '#save', function(){
    $("#table tr:gt(0)").each(function () {
    var this_row = $(this);
    var artist = $.trim(this_row.find('td:eq(1)').html());
    var title = $.trim(this_row.find('td:eq(2)').html());
    $.post('ajax/save.php', { 'artist': artist, 'title':title });
    });
 });
```

**PHP script:**

```
$artist=$_POST['artist'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$newartist = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($artist));
$newtitle = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($title));

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxx");
mysql_select_db("cdcol", $con);
$sql="INSERT INTO `table 3` (ARTIST, TRACKTITLE)
VALUES ('$newartist', '$newtitle')";
mysql_query( $sql, $con );
echo"Success";
?>
```

Comment: Tried [auto-increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)?

Comment: I have an auto-increment in place on an id field in the database which makes it easier to manipulate the database fields later. But this doesn't solve how to retain the HTML table row order when inserting new rows, does it? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Please explain _I will be regularly inserting the same table with different data in it each time_

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't making my point clear. I meant to say that if every time I ran the script I was inserting the rows in order using an ID of 1, 2 or 3, there would then be multiple and conflicting instances of these IDs in my database.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are talking about, but if the id is necessary to be repeated, keep it as a separate column, not primary key. If the ID is unique and your records change, then you should be using `update`. Check if the ID already exists in table, if exists `update` it else `insert` a new record. Or am I still way off from what you need?

Comment: Do you mean something like, every time you insert from the HTML, you need to keep a record of the order of _that set_? Like user enters id->1,2,3 that's one set. User later enters id->1,2,3,4 that's another set, that way?

Comment: Yep thats correct. In this case each HTML table row represents a track in a playlist. Currently the playlist order is lost when inserting that  table into the database

Comment: I think the best method is, since each set of records is being inserted together, you can keep a datetime column and `track_id`. When inserting track->1,2,3 track_id-> will be 1,1,1 , next time user enters track->4,5,6  track_id-> 2,2,2. You get what I mean? Using track_id and the datetime column, the record can be fetched in the same way it was inserted. Before you insert, get the `max(track_id)` from the table and increment by 1.

Comment: Oh, this is cool. Had never thought about time stamping the database records. Will give it a go. Thanks!